# Passing information using Firebase.Auth between functions in two different .dart files

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have three dart files that in theory should communicate with one another seamlessly.

The first is a wrapper.dart file that listens for authStateChanges() and opens a 'home.dart' file if authStateChanges() returns a valid user or a signIn.dart file if it returns null. See wrapper.dart below:

```
import 'package:brew_crew/screens/authenticate/sign_in.dart';
import 'package:brew_crew/screens/home/home.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
       const Wrapper({super.key});

       @override

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //Return either Home or Authenticate Widget

        return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {

         // Is User logged in or not
       if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
         // User is signed in, show Home widget
         return Home();
       } else {
         // User is not signed in, show Authenticate widget
         return SignIn();
            }          
       },
       ),
       );
       }
       }
```

The second is an auth.dart file where i have chosen to house all my authentication functions. I currently have three of them: `signInAnon()`, `signInEmailPass()` and `signUserOut()`. See auth.dart below:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';

class AuthService {

  // Instance of Firebase Auth 
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //using logger instead of print for production ready code
  final Logger _logger = Logger();

  // method for anonymous sign-in
  // Will not implement the below methods in the app

  Future<User?> signInAnon() async{

    try {

      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User? user = result.user;
      return user;

    } catch(e){
         _logger.e('Error: $e');
        return null;
    }
  }

  // method for email/password sign-in

         Future<User?> signInEmailPass(
            TextEditingController emailController, TextEditingController 
            passWordController) 
            async{

          try {
             // Access email and password from the controllers
            String email = emailController.text.trim();
      String password = passWordController.text.trim();

      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;
      return user;

    } catch(e){
         _logger.e('Error: $e');
        return null;
    }
  }

  // method for register with email and password 

  // method for sign-out
  void signUserOut(){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

In the event of a successful login, One can log out with the logout icon on the home page. Unfortunately this is where everything falls apart. **see below for home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:brew_crew/services/auth.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Home({super.key});
 
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
         IconButton(onPressed: _auth.signUserOut(), icon:const Icon(Icons.logout))]),
      body: const Center( // centering the column
        child: Text(
              'LOGGED IN'),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

I get this error home.dart

> This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
> Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.

i have tried using future in my sign out function to delay the return of void but that hasnt helped. Nothing i have tried has helped.